# Django upload many files & start working on them before all files are uploaded

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

Alright, I'm fairly new to asking questions here so bear with me.

I've got a Django app that is currently in production and I'm trying to access uploaded files as each one finishes uploading rather than after all files have completed the upload process.

The current solution:

1. Upload of 10000 files starts
2. Upload finishes
3. Backend analyzes files asynchronously and streams them to the front in cooperation with my JS.

The solution I'd like to implement:

1. Upload of 10000 files starts
2. Backend asynchronously analyzes the files as they come and streams them to the front end in cooperation with my JS
3. Upload finishes

**I honestly just don't know where to start here and I'd appreciate any indication of the right way to do this.**

Additional info:

- Application coded in Python3.11/Django4.2/CSS(2023)/JS(ECMAScript)
- Files are uploaded using a JS drag & drop datastream and submitted via a Django FileField with a forms.ClearableFileInput() that accepts multiple files
- Application deployed on a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server via Nginx & Gunicorn
- Each file analyzed can be anywhere from 17kb to 12mb
- By 'analyzes' I mean that calculations are run on each file to then my app produces a list of calculated values
- When I say that my backend 'asynchonously' analyzes the files I mean that I am using a ThreadPool to run my calculations in parallel

Comment: Have a look at this project; uses django under the hood and it's made for handling files, you can probably find some pretty cool code:  https://github.com/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx

Comment: @nigel239 Alright thanks, their solution of using Celery and a data broker might solve my problem. Looking into it now :)